# Ajax call to spring controller callback error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

Can you tell me what it's going wrong with the following ajax call to controller ?
The controller that is called via ajax :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userManagement/loadData.html", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces="text/plain")
public @ResponseBody String loadData(@RequestBody String jsonData) {
    try {
        Map<String, Object> data = JsonUtils.jsonAsMap(jsonData);
        pageSize = Integer.valueOf(data.get("pageSize").toString());
        pageNumber = Integer.valueOf(data.get("pageNumber").toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "failure";
    }
    return "success";
}
```

The ajax function :

```
function reloadUsers(){
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        cache : false, 
        dataType: 'json',  
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',
        url : "userManagement/loadData.html",
        data : JSON.stringify({
            pageSize : 10,
            pageNumber : 0
        }),
        success : function(response) {
            if(response.responseText=='true'){
                console.log('success');
            }else{
                console.log('server error');
            }
        },
        error : function(jqxhr){
            console.log('error');
            console.log(jqxhr.responseText);
        } 
    });
}
```

Now when i execute the ajax call to the controller it always goes on the error function and the **jqxhr.responseText** is always the value returned by the controller(in this case 'success' or 'failure'.
My question is why is this happening ? 
If i change the controller returned values to "true" or "false" the ajax successfully callback the 'success' function.

I also tried with `produces="application/json"`and got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `datatype` to:

```
 dataType: 'text',
```

As you are going to get a string in response because of this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userManagement/loadData.html", ....... produces="text/plain")
                                            //--------because of this-----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe that i missed that :)